# '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command - wdio

Tags: node.js, selenium

When I try to run the code `./node_modules/.bin/wdio config`

I have got this error:

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.

Package.json

```
"@wdio/cli": "^6.1.22",
"@wdio/local-runner": "^6.1.22",
"@wdio/mocha-framework": "^6.1.19",
"@wdio/spec-reporter": "^6.1.14",
"@wdio/sync": "^6.1.14",
"chai": "^4.2.0",
"chai-webdriverio": "^1.0.0",
"chromedriver": "^83.0.0",
"local-runner": "^0.1.1-alpha",
"wdio-chromedriver-service": "^6.0.3",
"webdriverio": "^6.1.11"
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1):

The dot slash annotation is not working on Windows, as where you can just leave that part out.

Linux / MacOS

> ./node_modules/.bin/wdio config

Windows

> node_modules/.bin/wdio config

Though, if you wanted to, you could use .\ and it would work.

> .\node_modules.bin\wdio config

The explination here is the difference between the directory separators along with the path.

`. = current directory`

`.. = parent directory`

`./` Mac, Linux, etc

`.\` Windows, Windows 2000, etc

Comment: Hi 
This works for me

\node_modules\.bin\wdio config

Thanks

Comment: @Anam no worries, don't forget to mark it as the answer once possible.